# How to view the signanature of APK file？

Tags: android, apk, sign

We know the way of get the info of *jks .

```
keytool -list -v -keystore *.jks
```

How to get the signature of a apk? Is there some method?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the APK name is suspect.apk
Go the path of suspect.apk in cmd or shell terminal.
Try the follow cmds:

1  get simple infomation of apk

```
jarsigner -verbose -verify suspect.apk
```

2  get signature detail

```
unzip -p suspect.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert
```

Answer (score 0):

To get details of APK signature you can use `apksigner`

- `apksigner verify suspect.apk`
- `apksigner verify  --print-certs  suspect.apk`
- `apksigner verify  -v  suspect.apk`

Refer the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#usage-verify)